# React Native Android Blank Space Between Status Bar And Header

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

i have created a react-native application.Using react-navigation/native for navigation. My android screen has a blank space between application header and android status bar. I can't do anything there. I tried inspecting but there is nothing to inspect.

`App.js`

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { HomePage } from './pages';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
export default App = () => {
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage}></Stack.Screen>
          </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
```

`index.js`

```js
import App from './src/App';
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";

Navigation.registerComponent('com.app.MyApp', () => App);
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            stack: {
                children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'com.app.MyApp'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[You can see the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmOCZ.png)

Why there is a huge blank space between my header and status bar?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why are you using two different navigation libraries? It can cause that problem.

Comment: Just stick to `react-navigation/..`, get rid of `react-native-navigation`. You don't need that index.js code. Usually the index.js just contains `AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)`

Comment: Why did i install two navigation package :( Thanks for helping. Silly question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did install two diffrent navigation package. Deleted one and works.